# Images uploading, going to the /media/tmp, but not saving in media/catalog after saving product [Magento]

Tags: image, magento, upload

As the title says, I’m having trouble saving the images for the products.

I edit a product (grouped product), go on images tab, upload an image (this wokrs fine, the image is there when I rollover and I can see its URL on the /tmp folder), choose the store views for it and proceed to save the product.

Check the frontend, no image. Check/edit the product again, no image there aswell. It just vanishes (although it stays in the /tmp folder).

Could you help me sort this out? I've set all permissions to 777 temporarily and still no luck.

Fixed: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4348/P45/#t327010

Comment: Is the image saved in media folder?

Comment: This was fixed. Solution here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4348/P45/#t327010

Comment: Can you provide an answer to this question?  Magento changed their boards, so that article isn't coming up.

Comment: @adpro that page is accessible via here: https://web.archive.org/web/20121227090555/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/4348/P45

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!!!
I experienced this issue after migrating from M1 to M2. When edit any product, add/delete image does not work. It shows when it is uploaded but after save it does not save. I have applied this query to solved the issue. here media_gallery attribute id is 703.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 703 and value = 0

DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 703 and value = NULL
```

Comment: It works perfect in Magento migration from 1.9.x to 2.3.
Get `attribute_id` running the query   

```sql
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'media_gallery'
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still facing the same problem, it may be because of the `prototype.js` version.

Change the `xxx.toJSON()` calls in js/mage/adminhtml/product.js to `Object.toJSON(xxx)`. For example from this:

```
$(this.idPrefix + 'save_attributes').value = this.attributes.toJSON();
```

to this:

```
$(this.idPrefix + 'save_attributes').value = Object.toJSON(this.attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when I migrated from M1 to M2.
 After debugging I found that in `eav_attribute` db table originally the backend_type for attribute `media_gallery` in M2 is set to `static` but after migration it got replaced by `varchar`.
 I have changed it back to `static` and form me image upload and save started to work for products.
Hope this will help.